# Line has wrong number of columns, but I can't find which line

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have this very big text file (about 2.5 Gb), which I need to load and put in a numpy array of 2 columns using Python. Somewhere in the text file the number of columns seems to be wrong, so it can't load it.

I am trying to find out where exactly this happens, so I can fix it. However, the line number I get is not much help. I would like to get the first value of the line.

The file looks like this:

```
1.001  1
1.002  0
1.003  3
1.004  1
etc...
```

I am opening the file like this:

```
import numpy as np

with open('paths 8_10.txt', 'r') as paths_list:
    for file_path in paths_list:
        with open(file_path.strip(), 'r') as file:
            data = np.loadtxt(file_path.strip())
            t = data[:,0]       
            x = data[:,1]
```

So I would like `t` at the location where the program crashes.

I was thinking about a for-loop which prints the value up until where it stops loading, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: posting the trace might help here.

Comment: Why is the line number you get not much help? That tells you exactly where the (first) problem line is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is not an issue, I suggest you write a small test harness as follows:

```
import csv

with open('paths 8_10.txt', 'rb') as paths_list:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(paths_list)

    for line_number, line in enumerate(csv_reader, start=1):
        if len(line) != 2:
            print "Line {} has {} columns: {}".format(line_number, len(line), line)
```

This would let you identify which entries need fixing for use in your main script.

If needed, this approach could easily be extended to skip over erroneous lines or truncate the extra columns and write out the file automatically, thus fixing it for future use.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, however for some reason it doesn't recognize the shape of the lines. If i do: print len(line), than al line are length 1. I think I should split the columns first, right? Do you know how?

Comment: Are there tabs between them? If so, change to `csv.reader(paths_list, delimiter='\t')`